# JavaScript optimization with nested loops

Tags: javascript

I have a huge array of points to draw on a canvas. Right now i am drawing every point by running a nested loop for x and y on the array of the data. This seems to be causing firefox to show a script has hanged notice.

What would be the best way to avoid that?

IMO some kind of parallel looping solution would be great, but the problem is i am not aware of any such method.

Comment: Need the code you are using to understand how to optimize it.

Comment: If you had a width of 1000 and a height of 1000 you would have to draw 1.000.000 points. That can't be improved by a better loop.

Comment: It can't be accelerated, but responsiveness can be restored: process in batches, each one started sequentially through setTimeout(), do not try to process too much at once. For example, after each full inner loop call the function via setTimeout() to start the next loop, don't do it inside the for loop which would not yield but be immediate.

Comment: I won't be drawing all the points, only some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just creating an image pixel by pixel, you're way better off doing it in an "image data" object and then dropping that into the canvas when you're done.  It's much, much cheaper to drop pixels into an array than it is to make canvas API calls pixel-by-pixel.

There's a method called "createImageData()" that you use to make an ImageData object, which is really just an array of pixels with height/width.  The pixels are organized as a simple linear array, with each group of four array elements representing a single pixel. The four values are just the red, green, and blue color values, and an alpha value for opacity.

When your code has filled in all the pixel values, you just call "putImageData()" to draw it to the canvas.